# Как экспортировать данные полученные парсингом в одном js файле, в другой

Tags: javascript, парсер, библиотеки

Решил освоить парсиннг. Грубо говоря имеется 3 файла: HTML, Main.js и pars.js (Main.js и pars.js лежат в одной папке). Страницу открываю через Live Server

Html: `<script type="module" src="../JS/main.js"></script>`

в файле pars.js Использую две js библиотеки axios и cheerio. Написать парсер и собрать нужные данные в массив получилось, но когда я попробовал экспортировать этот массив в Main.js для дальнейшего использования, то столкнулся с проблемой. Если импортировать библиотеки так:

```
                                                // pars.js
import axios from 'axios';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

const url = '@';
const capTextArray = [];

// Парсер
async function fetchData() {
  try {

    const capTextArray = await parswe();

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ERR', error);
  }
}

async function parswe() {
  try {

    const response = await axios.get(url);

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const html = response.data
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      $('p.question').each( (index, element) => {
        capTextArray.push($(element).text());
      });

      return(capTextArray);

    }

  } catch {
    console.error('ERR', error);
  }
}

fetchData();

export {capTextArray}; // попытка вывести массив
```

и добавить "type": "module" в package.json, то при попытке импорта в Main.js

`import { capTextArray } from '../JS/pars.js';`

браузер выдает данную ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Если же package.json не изменять и попытаться импортировать библиотеки данным образом:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
```

то export из pars.js работать не будет, а при попытке запросить массив в Main.js:

`const capTextArray = require('./pars.js');`

Браузер не переваривает require: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Как можно решить данную проблему? (смотрел в сторону Browserify, но не особо понимаю как с его файлом дальше работать). И возможно ли будет вообще с таким кодом вывести заполненный массив capTextArray, если он заполняется в асинхронной функции? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в браузере заимпортить модули для сборки. Так не получится. Используйте [подключаемые библиотеки CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/axios). В браузере вы сможете импортировать данные из одного вашего JS файла в другой.

Comment: Попробовал выбранные библиотеки и просто ссылкой в html подключать и в <script>,  но все еще есть ошибка: cheerio.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at cheerio.js:5:13, браузеру не нравится require в самой папке подключаемой библиотеки с CDN